# Multiple leave events generated in Custom widget in Qt

Tags: events, qt4, hover

I receive a Leave Event every time i move a pixel with my mouse over a customized QFrame i did. Why is this happening?.

I reimplemmented the leave and enter event as follows. As you can see i tried to comment the QFrame enterEvent, and restrict the repetition with a boolean, but it doesnt work because an enter and leave are continuously generated:

```
  void enterEvent(  QEvent *event   ){
    //QFrame::enterEvent(event);
    if (!mouseHover_)
    {
      mouseHover_ = true;
      emit hoverInSignal(""); 
    }
  }
  void      leaveEvent( QEvent *event   ){
    //QFrame::leaveEvent(event);
    if (mouseHover_)
    {
      SmartUIWrapper::Instance()->addInfoMessage("out");
      emit hoverOutSignal(); 
      mouseHover_ = false;
    }
  }
```

Does it have something to be with the focus?

Comment: I discovered that it depends on the movement direction.The frame is a square with a Pixmap inside. If i move downwards, only happens twice (which is wrong too...) , if i move upwards, every pixel emits one event. The same with left and right. Sometimes.... Weird stuff, this...

Comment: I found out more things. This QFrame is used all over my app. In other places, it WORKS perfectly. Just once. But the difference between those and this is just the content. The others have the same image, but bigger. And no text inside. But they are the same!

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the reason. 
I created a panel over this QFrame when i hovered.

When i moved the mouse, since the panel is positioned on the right bottom side of the cursor position, everytime i moved over the QFrame to the right or bottom, when i hovered this new panel i created, it looses the focus, so it gets closed again, then another hover comes, and then it´s created again... and again... everytime i hover the new panel.